# conditions for which matrix has all eigenvalues inside unit circle or on the unit circle

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, stability-theory

$\mathbf{M}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{I}&0&0&\cdots&0&0&0\\
0&\mathbf{I}&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&\mathbf{I}&0&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&\mathbf{I}&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&\mathbf{I}&0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

Given that $\mathbf{y}=\operatorname{diag}\left(y_i\right)$ and $\mathbf{x}=\operatorname{diag}\left(x_i\right) $ where each $i=1,2,\dots, N$, $y_i$ are $N\times N$ matrices whose eigenvalues are strictly less inside unit circle. $I$ are $N\times N$. For each $i$, $x_i$ are also $N\times N$.

Could anyone help me to find out under what condition(s) this matrix $\mathbf{M}$  has the property that modulus of its all eigenvalues strictly less than $1$ given that each block matrix in $\mathbf{y}$ are given that they all have eigenvalues less than $1$, for all $i$?

Thank you.

Comment: In other words, you are just asking for which pairs of complex numbers $x,y\in \bar {\mathbb D}$ all roots of the equation $z^m(z-y)+x$ lie in the closed unit disk. If $m\to\infty$, the corresponding region tends to $|x|+|y|\le 1$ but I do not think there is a nice answer for fixed finite $m$...

Answer (score 0):

We could deduce the conditions, given an approximate solution for eigenvector correspondent to the maximum eigenvalue, so, we could reformulate our objective into a simpler one.

When the maximum eigenvalue is a strictly less than 1 ?

---

Assuming than $M$ is a $(n, n)$ block matrix.

If $M$ is a diagonalizable matrix, then we could use the power iteration method.

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\mathbf{v_{k + 1}} = \mathbf{\frac{Mv_{K}}{||Mv_{K}||}}, 
\end{equation}

where $v_{k+i}$, is the best approximation for eigenvector correspondent to the maximum eigenvalue.

\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
\mathbf{v_{0}} = \begin{bmatrix}a_{0}\\a_{1}\\\vdots\\a_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

$a_{0},\ ... \ , a_{i}, \quad$  are vectors

Assuming we have started with $\mathbf{v_{0}} \succ 0$, then

\begin{equation} \label{eq3}
\mathbf{Mv_{0}} = \begin{bmatrix}a_{0} * x + a_{n} * y\\a_{1}\\\vdots\\a_{n}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

---

We are able to make a variety of assumptions on $x$ and $y$, to guarantee that the recursive relation is decreasing.